# Create pdf reports from Sql Server in ASP.NET MVC 2 application?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-2, pdf, reporting

I want to be able to somehow get reports out of my Sql Server database in an MVC application. I could have developed a way to do that using xml and then transform it to fo and rendered it via an fo processor to pdf. But that would require being able to have the fo processor installed on the web server, and I'm using a web host, so that's probably not going to work.

So I've seen Reporting Services mentioned here and there. Does that include the possibility to create pdfs? And if so, how do you use it in an MVC application? I tried before to mix webforms into MVC application (if that's necessary as I've seen implied) but couldn't make it work. The routing didn't seem to recognize the web form page...

Or is there any other easier way to create pdf reports from Sql Server data? I should also mention that I only use Linq (and the Entity Framework) to access data, so hopefully there is a solution that doesn't require me to know Sql stored procedures etc...

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/ a c# port of the iText open source java library for PDF generation. It is relatively straightforward to create simple PDFs using these libraries

Comment: Keep in mind that since 5.0, iText (and iTextSharp) are licensed under the AGPL license which is quite hostile towards commercial use.  You can buy licenses from iTextSoftware.com (they pay me to provide iText support).  The older versions are still available but are no longer supported.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it seems extremely complex, much too complex for the sort of internal use application I need it for...